# Google Maps fragment showing blank grey map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

I'm having problems with getting the map in my map fragment to show. I have tried several different solutions but the map remains blank (grey). Can somebody please point out what I'm doing wrong? The SHA1 fingerprint I'm using is the one I found in *Android > Build*.

*Note: where it says "api key from developers console", I of course have put the correct key.*

**Fragment01.java**

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment01 extends Fragment {
MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_01, container, false);
// Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
map = mapView.getMap();
map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

// Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
// Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
return v;
}
}
```

**Fragment01.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="se.sebastianliljegren.nellienovafoto"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
    <permission
android:name="se.sebastianliljegren.nellienova.foto.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission    android:name="se.sebastianliljegren.nellienovafoto.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="api key from developers console"/>
    <uses-library
android:name="com.google.android.maps"
android:required="true" /> 
    <activity
        android:name="se.sebastianliljegren.nellienovafoto.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What do you use for testing emulator or device?

Comment: I think you forget to put `.(dot)` after `nellienova` in `<uses-permission    android:name="se.sebastianliljegren.nellienovafoto.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>` in your `manifest.xml`. Correct first

Comment: @Erzer I'm using my HTC One X (Android 4.2.2).

Comment: @Sebbenator i mean issue is all about your `Package Name` that you used. What is your `Package` name that you used to generate a `API Key` from Dev console?

Comment: @SimplePlan The package name I used to generate the `API Key` is `se.sebastianliljegren.nellienovafoto`. So I corrected that (I had, as you pointed out, put the dot between nellienova and foto. So now it says `<permission android:name="se.sebastianliljegren.nellienovafoto.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/> <uses-permission android:name="se.sebastianliljegren.nellienovafoto.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>` but the map is still blank.

Comment: @Sebbenator uninstall your app and install again a fresh apk built.

Comment: @SimplePlan After un- and reinstalling the app, the map is still blank. Also the grid is gone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54771/discussion-between-simple-plan-and-sebbenator).

Comment: @SimplePlan I saw in the SDK Manager that my Google Play services wasn't up do date (revision 17). I've updated it now and will try again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are getting a grey map it's a communication issue with the servers. Recheck your api key, did you activate google map in the google map console for ANDROID ? is your package name correct in the console ? Are you 100% sure ? If there is doubt ReCreate a debug apikey or release. Also if the map is grey there must be some log, check your logcat for warnings from the api

Comment: The API I have activated is  `Google Maps Android API v2`. I have changed the package name to se.sebastianliljegren.nellienova and updated all the references in the manifest and the java files and generated a new API key but the map is still grey.

Comment: are you running it on real device or android emulator?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after change my Hard Disk.

My problem solved after I create New Api key whit New SHA1 on google console.