# For google maps api v2, what is the limit for creating new android maps key(s) and adding applications to single key

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have two queries regarding google maps api v2:

For one google api console account and in its one project

1. what is the maximum limit for creating new android key(s) for google
   maps api v2.
2. what is the maximum limit for adding applications (SHA1 certificate
   fingerprint and package name (separated by a semicolon) per line)
   inside one key using 'Edit allowed Android apps'

Currently i have scenario, where i have added around 108 application inside single maps key all are loading maps properly on device. But if I add any more applications maps are not loading on device just showing blank gray screen with zooming and current location buttons.

In logs its shows this messages

*Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).*

I had created New Android Key in same project and tried to use that new maps key, but still its having same above issue. I verified SH1 fingerprint, package name, signing key and its maps key all are proper.

I had searched lot related to this in google maps documentation and any related issues but didn't find any information.

Comment: try to clean the project and un install and re-install the app on device

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?csw=1#usagelimits

Comment: @QadirHussain tried cleaning project, re-install etc. din't worked. And the 'Google Maps Android API v2' service doesn't come in usage limit category list https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?csw=1#usage_apis

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not to limit the keys. 
Today Google's map service acting strange. 
I also created an application today and was not able to run the map as the other guys:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956567/adding-new-package-name-to-the-map-api-key-did-not-displayed-google-maps-from-ye
- [Google Maps fragment showing blank grey map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950734/google-maps-fragment-showing-blank-grey-map)
- [Google maps suddenly not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805769/google-maps-suddenly-not-working)
- etc

Answer (score 0):

I have 1 release key that's currently successfully being used by 3 apps that make use of `com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap`. I've created a new app that uses a different package name but the same key and credentials; the package name has been added to the Google console... yet the map is grey.

The release key is correct as it works for the other apps and the important stuff for the manifest is the same as the other apps including the `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY` - I don't understand why it does not work.

Initially I created a new key but that didn't work hence why I tried the above approach that should work as it's been tried and tested.

Note: I've cleared the cache and uninstalled the app from the device but still no luck.

Very frustrating.